# Is it possible for web3 to listen to contract function call ? (For example mint() for a NFT)

Tags: web3js, javascript, events

Hey I have read about listening to events in web3js and it worked.
I have my abi set up and looked through all available events in it and mint(),
what I use to mint nfts is a function which makes sense, so how would it be possible for me to listen at my specific contract adress when the mint() function is called ?

Answer (score 2):

You need your smart contract address, your ABI and web3js.

But you need also a node that actually work with ethereum blockchain.

You can do your local node (but it will take long time to sync and a very large memory space) or you can use Infura.io that give you API key so they send to you event from the blockchain.